# Responsive Layout - Media Queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

When I adjust the screen size , the orange line which is defined by a h1 tag doesn't move downwards with the text and also my orange boxes that i had floated to the right merge behind the text.

I know I need to include Media Queries somehow but no idea how, can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly you want? this sentence "South Leeds Alternative Trading Enterprise" want to move downwards

Comment: Its hard to write reponsive for your site because your style #Timings {margin-top: -265px;}  and div not properly created

Comment: @Emmabritnor you need to keep the styling as seperate as you can from the style dont' position elements on page using br's use css to style thing position them and size them and good luck!

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77392/responsive-layout-media-queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, first of all I don't think I have ever seen anyone use as many breaks `<br>` tags on a single page as you have haha.

The answer to your question is to simply use the `<hr>` tag (horizontal rule), wherever you want a line.

For example after the closing div tag for timings add the `<hr>` tag. By default the `<hr>` tag is styled black so we need to add some simple styling to your stylesheet.css

```
hr {
    border-top: 1px solid #bd6e22;
}
```

If you wanting to add spacing above, below or even both then add this to the styling.

```
hr {
    border-top: 1px solid #bd6e22;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

I have put 20px for an example but you can change that to what ever you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes if you want add space above, below or even both then you can add margin. I'll update my answer ^

Comment: give them width's using % that way they will adapt then use a meda query to set them to 100% when you hit a certain screen width

Comment: @vimes1984, that sounds easier said that done, she's a learner.
Emma Britnor, the way you have structured the divs currently isn't great to be honest. It's pretty simple to do but I would have to write a bunch of code out, it's going to look messy if I put it in a comment.

Comment: Direct message me if you're wanting further help with the layout, glad I could help with your line issue.

Comment: add me in a chat window and I'll see if i can help

Comment: @EmmaBritnor I thought you could direct message on here but I guess not haha.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77392/responsive-layout-media-queries I'll be in here @jordan

Answer (score 0):

Ok you need to open up http://me14evb.leedsnewmedia.net/slate/stylesheet.css in a ftp client. 
then https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ use the @media quieres for each page break size and adjust the style's accoridng to each device :D 
good luck! 
Chris

Comment: This won't fix the line. This just adjusts the `<br>` (Page break) size.

Comment: she asks how to include media quieres: <cite>I know I need to include Media Queries somehow but no idea how, can anyone help me?</cite>

Comment: the page isn't coded right in the slightest way but hey ho... she shouldn't be using floats but flex boxes. She shouldn't be using any tag inside the class="line" at all it's not needed... I'd have started of with a css framework to do the heavy lifiting but people need to leanr at there own pace :D

Comment: hehehe srry!! It wasn't meant at a diss at you more in response to the comment that was left here by Julian which was later deleted...It's not a bad first effort but in the future I would look into using a css framework ( bootstrap, foundation,.....) using one will fix most of your responsive needs out of the box and do most of the css heavy lifting for you.